# Git rebase since the last merge operation

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Let's consider this situation where I work on a particular feature on separate branch:

```
* 456789 bar (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
| * 3456789 foo (HEAD -> feature)
| *   2345678 Merge origin/master in feature
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 1234567
```

Some time ago I merged the `master`, but since then I did `foo` on my feature while somebody did `bar` on the `master`.

Now, I would like to rebase `bar` right before my last merge:

```
* 3456789 foo (HEAD -> feature)
* 2345678 Merge origin/master in feature
|\
| |  
| |
* | 456789 bar (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
```

I tried a `git rebase master` from `feature`. The problem is that Git wants to replay all my changes on the top of the master which can be a lot of work.

One possible solution would be this:

```
$ git checkout -b temp feature~3
$ git merge master
$ git cherry-pick foo -n2
$ git branch -D feature
$ git branch -m temp feature
$ git checkout feature
$ git branch -D temp
```

I am sure there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described at the end of your question is a good way to do it.

Here you can figure and understand what is going on.
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

---

Another option is to do a `sqaush`

As squash is an ***`interactive rebase`*** which allow you to modify any commit you wish in any way. Using the edit command you can edit and add any commits at any given point of the history.

---

In order to do a git squash follow those steps:

```
// X is the number of commits you wish to squash, in your case 6
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `e` for edit and the manipulate the desired commits.

If you wish to keep the commit as is so you should use what you have suggested with the `git cherry-pick`

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand how `git rebase -i` will help me in this case. In my example `2345678` has two parents. I want its second parent `1234567` to become `456789`.

Comment: edit the desired commit before the merge and set the new content you want it to contain, merge has 2 parents, you can can checkout any of the parents.